# Sql Server 2005 Not Compatible with Windows 10

Tags: sql-server-2005, compatibility, windows-10

I had SQL Server 2005 working when I upgraded to Windows 10. Now it won't work. I read that it is not compatible with Windows 8, according to Microsoft. Windows 10 is but the matured version of Windows 8, to me. Is there any way I can get SQL Server 2005 to work with Windows 10?

Comment: Have you looked into compatibility mode? http://www.windows10forums.com/articles/compatibility-mode.7/

Comment: I tried that with a previous application and it did not work. But this not just an application is also has services that are running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to apply / re-apply SP4? I'm not saying it will work but it works in Windows 8. Not sure what you upgraded from.

This may help .. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cj859zcWhEM

Comment: Nice! Thanks! Will keep this in mind for future use. I had downgraded at the time as it was an urgent case.

Answer (score 1):

uninstall inFlow before upgrading to Windows 10 and then re-install (because of compatibility issues with SQL Server 2005). This is pretty easy and can be done from the START menu by searching “Programs and Features” and once open, choosing to uninstall inFlow Inventory.

Not sure which version of SQL you’re using? You can check the version of SQL Server through the START menu by searching “Programs and Features.” In that window, look for “Microsoft SQL Server” and check the version (it will either be 2005 or 2008 R2). If you’re in 2008 R2 or 2012 you’re golden, no extra steps required).

So bottom line: if you’re planning to take advantage of the upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 10 that’s great, but take a few minutes to double check your SQL Server version (as noted above) before you upgrade.  Most of us won’t be affected but if you don’t, the upgrade could break inFlow and that’s no fun at all!

Comment: At the time I changed SQL Server Express. Was much simpler for me and worked. Thanks for the update.