# Can't install SQL Server 2005 on Win10 x64

Tags: sql-server-2005, windows-10

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2005 on my Win10 x64.

The problem is I can't even select the Database Services and Reporting services I need cause checkbox is disabled.
[image]

I had a bit research on this issue but everyone else seems to have problems after the installation began, whereas, I can't even start the progress.

I tried *Run program made for previous versions of windows* and extract then install sqlncli.msi from SP4 according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935223/installing-sql-server-2005-on-windows-8).
Neither of them enable the checkboxes and I'm running out of ideas.

Should I install sp4 without install SQL Server first? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: SQL Server 2005 is long past its prime - you should install a much more recent version of SQL Server - 2014, 2016 or 2017 are the three most recent ones.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the Visual Studio subscriptions and turns out you can still download the original version of SQL Server 2005 by downloads search(autocomplete won't show it but the search result will).

And the checkboxes are enabled in this version.
If you face problem during the installation, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28144019/sql-server-2005-not-compatible-with-windows-10) works for me.